# Google places localities sof particular cities and country

Tags: android, google-places-api

I want to achievesomething like this [Places picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alD2o.png) i know how to do that with using google places autocomplete api but my question is that as you saw in the image it shows results of particular country and cities with localities.How i can do this the priority in the image is india and how i do this with priority country of my choices and also it autocomplete the result as well.Because i want to use this in showin map [Like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARglF.png)

Help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [AutocompleteFilter](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter) and apply it to the PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder.

Here's an example of a filter:

```
AutocompleteFilter autocompleteFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
     .setCountry("IN")
     .build();
```

This should restrict the results to India only.

Note: The country code has to be a ISO 3166-1 2 letter country code for the filter to work and it's also case sensetive - otherwise no country filter will be taken into consideration.

For additional filters use [AutocompleteFilter.Builder.setTypeFilter](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.Builder.html#setTypeFilter(int))

To apply the filter simply use [PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder.setFilter](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder.html#setFilter(com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter))

Comment: it should the the complete localities and sublocalities of city..?

Comment: Setting country will only limit results to that country specifically, including everything: cities and specific addresses.

If you want to be more specific use setTypeFilter: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter.Builder.html#setTypeFilter(int)